# Creating CSV file using PHP have wrong row

Tags: php

I have CURL request and getting response like below format

```
Workout Timestamp,Live/On-Demand,Instructor Name,Length (minutes),Fitness Discipline,Type,Title,Class Timestamp,Total Output,Avg. Watts,Avg. Resistance,Avg. Cadence (RPM),Avg. Speed (mph),Distance (mi),Calories Burned,Avg. Heartrate,Avg. Incline,Avg. Pace (min/mi)
2020-12-18 09:00 (CST),On Demand,Denis Morton,5,Stretching,Pre & Post-Ride Stretch,5 min Post-Ride Stretch,2020-12-16 08:00 (CST),,,,,,,12,,,
2020-12-18 10:26 (CST),On Demand,Leanne Hainsby,5,Stretching,Pre & Post-Ride Stretch,5 min Post-Ride Stretch,2020-12-13 10:45 (CST),,,,,,,,,,
2020-12-18 10:27 (CST),On Demand,Christine D'Ercole,5,Cycling,Low Impact,5 min Cool Down Ride,2020-12-18 08:00 (CST),,,,,,,,,,
```

I am trying to generate CSV file from it like below

```
$response = str_replace("Avg. Pace (min/mi)","Avg. Pace (min/mi),",$response);
    $data = explode(",",$response);
    
    $finalData =  array_chunk($data,18);
    
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$csv_filename.'"');

    $fp = fopen('downloads/'.$csv_filename, 'wb'); 
        
    foreach($finalData as $finalVal)
    {
      
      $finalVal = array_map('trim', $finalVal);
      fputcsv($fp, $finalVal);

    }
    fclose($fp);
```

Its work fine but if there two or more rows and last column have empty value, my column not coming properly in csv.

$finalData is looking like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Workout Timestamp [1] => Live/On-Demand [2] => Instructor Name [3] => Length (minutes) [4] => Fitness Discipline [5] => Type [6] => Title [7] => Class Timestamp [8] => Total Output [9] => Avg. Watts [10] => Avg. Resistance [11] => Avg. Cadence (RPM) [12] => Avg. Speed (mph) [13] => Distance (mi) [14] => Calories Burned [15] => Avg. Heartrate [16] => Avg. Incline [17] => Avg. Pace (min/mi) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2020-12-18 09:00 (CST) [1] => On Demand [2] => Denis Morton [3] => 5 [4] => Stretching [5] => Pre & Post-Ride Stretch [6] => 5 min Post-Ride Stretch [7] => 2020-12-16 08:00 (CST) [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => 12 [15] => [16] => [17] => 2020-12-18 10:26 (CST) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => On Demand [1] => Leanne Hainsby [2] => 5 [3] => Stretching [4] => Pre & Post-Ride Stretch [5] => 5 min Post-Ride Stretch [6] => 2020-12-13 10:45 (CST) [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => [15] => [16] => 2020-12-18 10:27 (CST) [17] => On Demand ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Christine D'Ercole [1] => 5 [2] => Cycling [3] => Low Impact [4] => 5 min Cool Down Ride [5] => 2020-12-18 08:00 (CST) [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => [15] => ) )
```

[image]

However it should something like this
[image]

Header is fine and fixed but blank column causing issue, I am not getting idea whats the issue and How I can resolve it.

Let me know if someone can help me for solve the puzzle. thanks!

Comment: It would help to post the $finalData value.

Comment: You're doing some very weird things with the response here. Why are you adding that extra comma after Avg Pace? What exactly is the format of the response? All a single string? It seems to be returning CSV values, but how does it differentiate between different rows?

Comment: @El_Vanja its giving response same as I have posted, I think its multi line string.

Comment: @JasonK I have added that array output. Thanks!

Comment: If it's multiline, then you should first explode by newline to get all the rows as separate elements and then afterwards explode by comma to get individual values. The one comma you add manually after Avg Pace doesn't make any sense and is throwing the whole thing off.

Comment: @El_Vanja, Thanks for point, Can You please help me for same? I am trying from last two hours but no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of your problem is that you're not separating your data properly. From the example you've shown, rows seem to be separated by a new line. So the first thing you'd need to do is replace `$data = explode(",",$response);` with `$data = explode(PHP_EOL, $response);` (note that `PHP_EOL` might not work for you as the response might be using a different character, but you can test it to find out).

Once you do that, you'll end up with an array containing each row from the response, like so:

```
array (
  0 => 'Workout Timestamp,Live/On-Demand,Instructor Name,Length (minutes),Fitness Discipline,Type,Title,Class Timestamp,Total Output,Avg. Watts,Avg. Resistance,Avg. Cadence (RPM),Avg. Speed (mph),Distance (mi),Calories Burned,Avg. Heartrate,Avg. Incline,Avg. Pace (min/mi)',
  1 => '2020-12-18 09:00 (CST),On Demand,Denis Morton,5,Stretching,Pre & Post-Ride Stretch,5 min Post-Ride Stretch,2020-12-16 08:00 (CST),,,,,,,12,,,',
  2 => '2020-12-18 10:26 (CST),On Demand,Leanne Hainsby,5,Stretching,Pre & Post-Ride Stretch,5 min Post-Ride Stretch,2020-12-13 10:45 (CST),,,,,,,,,,',
  3 => '2020-12-18 10:27 (CST),On Demand,Christine D\'Ercole,5,Cycling,Low Impact,5 min Cool Down Ride,2020-12-18 08:00 (CST),,,,,,,,,,',
)
```

Then you can iterate that array and explode on comma like you did:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $values = array_map('trim', explode(',', $row)));
    fputcsv($fp, $values);
}
```

This way you can completely drop the `$finalData =  array_chunk($data,18);` part, as you're no longer dependent on grabbing equally sized chunks from an array of all individual values.

Answer (score 0):

your response data is already in the desired format, no need to run it through fputcsv and convert to array and vice versa. Just read it line by line.

```
  $stream = fopen('php://memory','r+');
  fwrite($stream, $response);
  rewind($stream);

  $pftarget = fopen('target.csv', 'w');
  while (($row = fgets($stream,4096)) !== false) {
      fwrite($pftarget, $row);
  }
```